# Module with extensive list of RGB colors to create dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, colors, rgb

I'd like to create a long dictionary of RGB colors, e.g.,

```
{'blue': (0, 0, 150), 'black': (0, 0, 0), 'green': (0, 150, 0), 'red': (150, 0, 0)}
```

However, I'd like a extensive dictionary containing many color. I have been unable to find a module that contains information like this.
I am aware I could crawl a website that has this information, but I would prefer to simply import it from a module.

Does such a module resource exist? If not, are there other easy solutions to this problem?

Comment: Or this? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webcolors/1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what set of colors you're looking for the web colors might be a good set. There are libraries others have written for these, like [`webcolors`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webcolors/).

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have found module which can give a dictionary of colors with names (real color name in css) and hex values. Here I have post the code and you can see the result.

```
import matplotlib

rgb_colors = {}
for name, hex in matplotlib.colors.cnames.items():
    rgb_colors[name] = matplotlib.colors.to_rgb(hex)

print(rgb_colors)
```

You asked this question 3 years before, anyway I think my answer may be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Refer: https://pypi.org/project/colordict/

You can get a dictionary  of RGB Colors like this:

```
from colordict import ColorDict
colors = ColorDict()
print(colors)
```

You will get almost all the colors you will ever need.

```
Output: {'aliceblue': (240.0, 248.0, 255.0, 255.0), 'antiquewhite': (250.0, 235.0, 215.0, 255.0), 'aqua': (0.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0), 'aquamarine': (127.0, 255.0, 212.0, 255.0)... }
```

You can access color values using their names as key:

```
red = colors['red']
```